# How to uninstall Quest product(s) managed by quest installer

Tags: windows, windows-10, uninstall, windows-error-reporting

I have installed Knowledge Xpert for Oracle Administration from quest software in Windows10.

It automatically installed the below two softwares:

- Knowledge Xpert Engine.
- Knowledge Xpert Oracle Common.

Now, I have uninstalled Knowledge Xpert for Oracle Administration, but I'm unable to uninstall Knowledge Xpert Engine and Knowledge Xpert Oracle Common.

I can't find their installed files.

I found "Quest Software" installed from my control panel. But I'm unable to uninstall it because of the below error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using Revo uninsaller I have successfully uninstalled all the above mentioned softwares with ease.
First we need to install Revo uninstaller and then select the programs to be uninstalled.